# C/C++: duplicate main() loop in many threads

Tags: windows, multithreading, visual-c++

I have this "interesting" problem. I have this legacy code that looks like

```
int main()
{
  while(true) {
    doSomething();
 }
}
```

I would like to duplicate that doSomething() in many threads, so that now main() would look like

```
int main() {
  runManyThreads(threadEntry)
}

void threadEntry() {
   while(true) {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

The problem is that doSomething() access many global and static variables, and I cannot alter its code. Is there a trick to duplicate those static variables, so each thread has its own set ? (somekind of thread local storage, but without affecting doSomething())..
I use VisualC++

Comment: Aren't you concerned about race conditions?

Comment: Run an OS that can `fork()` efficiently? 'Course, then you'd have to solve the IPC issues that were previously dealt with by the threading system, so you're still looking at the possibility of lots of work...

Comment: @dmckee: Visual C++ does not run on any system which can `fork` efficiently.

Comment: @Billy: I know. It started as pure snark, but I chickened out and wrote the disclaimer about what that "solution" would actually cost...

Comment: @dmckee, @Billy, yes that's my fallback plan. Why do you think windows won't be able to handle 500-600 processes ? The fork() shouldn't be too efficient, as I would fork() only once per instance at the beginning..

Comment: @bugspy: I don't know about modern windows, but for a long time it was notorious for slow forks (but had efficient threads). Long flame wars have been held over the relative merits of unix forks and windows threads. Thus the snark.

Comment: @dmckee: This hasn't changed any.  Forking depends on processes having lightweight boundaries, while Windows has heavily armored processes.  As a result, the right way to port forks to Windows is to replace them with threads.

Comment: @bugspy.net: Windows does not support `fork` in **any** description. The only way to get to it is to use cygwin, which is slow because it's a compatibility layer.

Answer (score 4):

To make a long story short, no, at least not (what I'd call) reasonably.

Under the circumstance of not wanting to change `doSomething()`, your best bet is probably to run a number of copies of the existing process instead of attempting to use multi-threading. If each thread is going to use a separate copy of global variables and such anyway, the difference between multithreading and multiple processes will be fairly minor in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I think you can do something like:

```
#define threadlocal __declspec(thread)
```

And then put `threadlocal` before all the variables that should be local to the thread. Might not work though, it's generally not a good idea to just throw functions into threads when they weren't written to be multi-threaded.

Comment: I'm with Jerry on this not being a reasonable option.

Comment: As usual, I appreciate your candor.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is [thread local storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686749%28VS.85%29.aspx).